# duplicate instance of a jquery photo gallery

Tags: jquery

i'm using the following photo gallery:
http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

it's working perfectly in my website but when i try to duplicate it's instance as i want to show it twice within one page the display is getting messed up.

how can i initialize two different instances without affecting the photo gallery display.

PS: i'm duplicating the instance by just coping the divs holding and shaping the photo gallery twice.

thx,

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var galleries1 = $('.ad-gallery1').adGallery({ . . .

var galleries2 = $('.ad-gallery2').adGallery({ . . .
```

Make sure the two divs exist in your html.

Comment: thx for the reply O. what do i do with id? <div id="gallery" class="ad-gallery">, can i just leave two same ids? what about other variables?